# I am implementing select/deselect on div element. I am able to select the div on one click but not able to de-select it on next click on same div?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am implementing list of user names with div using for loop. I want to select div on first click and de-select on next click.

I have tried select code but not able to deselect on second click.

**TS**:

```
selected: any = [];

selectItem(obj, idx) {
  this.selected[idx++] = obj;
  console.log('Here are selected', this.selected);
}

deleteUser(): void {
  console.log(this.selected);

  if (confirm('Are you to delete user ?')) {
    for (var user in this.selected) {
      this.apiserv.deleteUser(this.selected[user].id).subscribe((data: User) => {
        this.getAllUser();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let u of users; let idx = index" class="user-item" (click)="selectItem(u,idx)">
  <div class="item-wrp">
    <div class="select-item item-block">
      <div [ngClass]="{'selectedDiv': idx == selected}" class="select-stl">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-list-item>
```

I want implement multiselect on this list with de-select option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to store all the selected items in your `selected` array.

Then in your TS file

```
selectItem(obj, idx) {
    this.selected[idx] = !this.selected[idx] ? obj : null;
    console.log("Here are selected", this.selected);
}
```

and in your template, change the `[ngClass]` as follows

```
<div [ngClass]="{'selectedDiv': selected[idx]}" class="select-stl">
    // Display list item
</div>
```

Here we are sending the index of the selected user on click and storing that user's data at that same index in `selected`. On deselect we are replacing the data with null.

Comment: That worked really well @nash11.
thanks you so much.

Comment: @Shripad - If this helped you, kindly mark it as correct :) Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers